# Projection on a Non-Orthonormal Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm just here to ask if there is anything dramatic or marginally more complex when you project a vector onto a subspace that is not defined by an **orthonormal basis**. We are currently studying an elementary course, and the strict definition of projections onto **subspaces** emphasizes the fact that the basis of the subspace is **orthonormal**. What could go wrong otherwise?

Comment: Naturally the subspace doesn't change whether you use an orthonormal basis or not. The *computation* of the orthogonal projection may be more complicated, however, than the convenient case of using an orthonormal basis.

Comment: In  an inner-product space the orthogonal projection of a vector v onto a  closed linear subspace S is not dependent on choice of basis for S. It is a function of v and S. If however you compute it by applying the computational formula that uses an orthonormal basis for S, to a basis for S that is not orthonormal,the chances of being right are between slim and none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the basis of your subspace is just orthogonal (not normalized) then nothing major changes: you just have to divide each term by the norm squared of the basis vector.  However if your basis is **not** orthogonal even then you've got two options:

1. Orthogonalize your basis vectors via the Gram-Schmidt process and then proceed as normal
2. Find the **dual basis** for that subspace

Each of the above is a bit more complex (but just a little bit) than simply using the projection formula.  If you want more info, just let me know in a comment below.